# Can I save the seasoning on my cast iron skillet or do I need to strip it and start anew?

Tags: cast-iron, skillet

I have a Lodge 12" cast iron skillet that I have been cooking in almost every night for about 6 months. I recently scrubbed a little to hard and created a "bald" spot into he middle of my pan. I wanted to know if I can save it or do I need to strip it and reason it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had success in restoring bald spots in my cast iron skillet.  After cooking and cleaning, I add oil when the skillet is warm.  Eventually the "bald" spot fills in.  Mine took about 3 months of 1-2 weekly uses.

Comment: Thanks B540Glenn! I'm cooking bacon in it right now.

Comment: I too cooked bacon to help with the re-seasoning. :-)